# ASP.NET MVC get value from DropDownList() usingn FormCollection

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a simple drop down list in Razor syntax:

```
@{
   List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
   listItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1 kg", Value = "1" });
   listItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "2 kg", Value = "2" });
   listItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "3 kg", Value = "3" });
   listItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "4 kg", Value = "4" });
   listItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "5 kg", Value = "5" });
   }
   @Html.DropDownList("Weight", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)listItems, new { @class = "form-control" })
   @Html.Hidden("Weight", 0)
```

I also have a Controller action which gets the data from the form via `FormCollection` defined as:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddProductsToCart(FormCollection collection /*int ?Id*/)
    {
        MyDBContext myDBContext = new MyDBContext();
        var value = collection["Weight"];
    }
```

But here I'm not able to get value of selected index in the Drop Down List in the `collection` upon submitting the form. Instead, I get `1, 1, 1` as the only single key in `collection`.

Any idea would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Have you tried: string strDDLValue = Request.Form["Weight"].ToString();

Comment: Why are you using `FromCollection` instead of binding to a model? And why do you have a hidden input for `Weight` as well?

Comment: Unless you are working with dynamic forms, you really should follow @StephenMuecke's advice and use a proper ViewModel

Comment: What do you mean by _I get 1, 1, 1 as the only single key in collection_ , Don't you get the value of selected Dropdown in `var data` ??

Comment: @PrashantPimpale yes i use Request.From but it returns 1,1,1

Comment: @ZiaulKabirFahad don't know why it retunrs 1,1,1

Answer (score 0):

As I tried your code in ASP.NET MVC 4 application,

The HTML is having two same Id for two HTML controls as:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Weight", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)listItems, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.Hidden("Weight", 0)
```

So when you access the data from FormCollection class it finds the two Id on the HTML so it separates each control value by Comma `,` like [Not sure why]:

[image]

So If you want only one value from View for that particular control you can use one variable which is the same name as control name in the method like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddProductsToCart(/*Might be no need of this*/ FormCollection fc, string Weight)
{
   var selectedValue = Weight;
   return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks all for your kind response.
FormCollection was returning the values of all the dropdowns which was in view.